# How to use a for loop with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am scraping data off of Facebook Marketplace. What I want to do is use puppeteer to: 
1) Create a nodelist of all my listings names
2) Use a for loop to click the listing name to pull up more info pop up
3) Scrape the data from the pop up and save it to an array 
4) Close the pop up
5) Repeat the process for every listing to return the array data

Here is my code that is currently not working:

```
const postClick = async (page) => {
      await page.evaluate(() => {
//Capture the nodelist of listing names
            let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('#marketplace-modal-dialog-title');
//If the nodelist of listings exist 
            if(buttons.length) {
//Loop through all listing names
              for(let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
                let button = buttons[i];
//click the listing
                button.click();
//wait for the X button to appear
                async (page) => {
                  await page.waitForSelector("button._3-9a._50zy._50-1._50z_._5upp._42ft");
                  await page.waitFor(5000)
                  await page.evaluate(() =>{
//click the X button
                  document.querySelector('button._3-9a._50zy._50-1._50z_._5upp._42ft').click();            
                });
                }
              }

            }
          });
        }
```

Then I am calling this right before browser close here:

```
await postClick(page);
```

I am not receiving an error but the code does not run. As soon as I take out the for loop and let button = buttons[0]; the code runs for the first item only.

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: @SublimizeD I edited it

Comment: Try this ```for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
                let button = buttons[i];```

Comment: That throws an Error. Unexpected identifier for int

Comment: My last suggestion would be ```var i;    for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) { let button = buttons[i];```

Comment: `page.evaluate` executes function in the page context, don't use `page` within evaluate, you should get the elements using `page.$$` and loop through it in the puppeteer context. look at @hretic example

Answer (score 3):

`#marketplace-modal-dialog-title` capturing element by id suggest only 1 item exists in the page since id should be unique ... i dont know why face book have multiple elements with the same id  , but perhaps js is reacting to this and captures 1 element only

try capturing buttons by class

```
let buttons = await page.$$('._50f4._50f7');
```

or whatever `document.querySelectorAll` equivalent of this is (you can capture multiple elements into an array by using `page.$$` )

also `buttons.length` returns a number by `if(buttons.length)` you're checking for `true` or `false` not the number so it should be  `if(buttons.length > 0)` altho some languages consider `0` as false and this works but its not a good idea in general

i cant test this code right now there might be soem errors but this is what i would do

```
// capture all the items in the marketplacee
let elements = await page.$$('._7yc._4e36');
// loop trough items
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {

    // capturing button and its text
    let  button  =  await elements[i].$('._50f4._50f7');
    let  button_text = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerText, button);
    console.log(button_text);

    //  click the  button
    await button.click();

    // wait for the popup to show up
    await page.waitForSelector('.uiLayer' , {  visible: true , timeout: 0 });
    //close the popup
    await page.click('._3-9a._50zy');


}
```

also i noticed the page url changes when you open pop up this might cuze problems and give you `Execution context was destroyed` error  ... so you might have to collect all the links and open them in new tabs

Comment: I am getting stuck on the first part. let buttons = await page.$$('._4ist._50f4._5kx5'). That returns a crazy looking object and not the nodelist of the title names. How do I get just the nodelist

Comment: @klaurtar1 `page.$$` returns an array of `ElementHandle`. take a look at puppeteer's docs https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.0.0/docs/api.md#class-elementhandle.

Comment: Ok I ran your code and for whatever reason it is saying cannot read property 'click' of null. I believe the button is undefined. Very confusing

Comment: @klaurtar1 the selectors might be different. check to see if the selector returns the correct element. This is merely an example, you need to change it based on your need.

Comment: I know. I changed it to let elements = await page.$$('._4ist._50f4._5kx5'); which is the classes of the titles of the listings. I also tried ('span[title]') which is the selector for the titles as well. Still did not work